# Ansible copy file using command syntax

Tags: ansible

The assignment is as follows:

Lets create a file touch afile.txt, prior to creating tasks

Create a playbook test.yml to

copy afile.txt from your control machine to host machine at /home/ubuntu/ location as afile_copy.txt and
debug the above task to display the returned value
Execute your playbook (test.yml) and observe the output

I did following

1. Created the afile_copy.txt using touch
2. created the playbook as follows:

---

```
- name: copy files
  hosts: all
  tasks: 
    - name: copy file
      command: cp afile.txt /home/ubuntu/afile_copy.txt
      register:output
    - debug: var=output
```

When I run the playbook using the command
ansible-playbook -i myhosts test.yml
it fails with the error message

stderr: cp: cannot stat 'afile.txt' : no such file or directory

The afile.txt is present in directory /home/scrapbook/tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You should use copy module instead of command module. command module executes on the remote node.

Answer (score 0):

1)**first execute the ad-hoc command for copy:**

ansible all -i myhosts -m copy -a "src=afile.txt dest=/home/ubuntu/"

### 2) After execute the above command,execute this playbpook:

- hosts: all
  tasks:

  - stat: path=/home/ubuntu/afile_copy.txt

    register: st
  - name: rename

    command: mv afile.txt /home/ubuntu/afile_copy.txt

    when: not st.stat.exists

    register: output
  - debug: var=output

Comment: use hypen "-" instead of dot.

Comment: use hypen "-" instead of dot(- hosts:all, - stat: ...., - name: ......, - debug: .....)

Answer (score 0):

Copy module should be used instead of command module

```
- name: copy files
  hosts: all
  tasks: 
    - name: copy file
      copy: src=afile.txt dest=/home/ubuntu/afile_copy.txt
      register:output
    - debug: var=output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
---
- name: copy files
  hosts: all
  tasks: 
    - name: copy file
      copy: 
        src: afile.txt 
        dest: /home/ubuntu/afile_copy.txt
      register: output
    - debug: var=output
```

Comment: You should include some commentary about the change, you've added a header and defined the command differently, so you should explain why you've done that

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.